# How to update rows values with other rows values from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have the following table:

Parameters

```
id, ownerId, paramId, value
1,    500,    100,    12345
2,    500,    100,    54321
3,    500,    101,      900
4,    500,    101,      901
5,    501,    101,      888
6,    501,    101,      777
```

Expected result:

Parameters

```
id, ownerId, paramId, value
1,    500,    100,      900
2,    500,    100,      901
3,    500,    101,      900
4,    500,    101,      901
5,    501,    101,      777
6,    501,    101,      777
```

I am trying to update the firs two rows values with the values from the last two rows, generally, I wish to update the value from 100 paramId with the value from 101 paramId where I have the same ownerId.

I am trying with the following script:

```
Update Parameters 
    set value = t1.value
    from Parameters t1
    where ownerId = t1.ownerId AND paramId = 100 And t1.paramId = 101
```

This script returns (0 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 0):

both your rows with ids 3 & 4 have same data for columns ownerId, paramId and value. You will need to filter by column id to update your rows.
Something like:

> Update Parameters 
>       set value = (select value from Parameters where id=3) where id = 1
>
> Update Parameters 
>       set value = (select value from Parameters where id=4) where id = 2

Comment: that is a solution but I need something generally to update my whole table without specifying the ownerId, because I can have more owners. I'm gonna update the table

Answer (score -1):

You may need to clarify why record 1 should be updated with the value from record 3 and record 2 should be updated with the value from record 4? But this will work otherwise...

```
update
    p
set 
    p.value = t.value
from 
    Parameters p
join 
    Parameters t
on
    t.ownerId = p.ownerId
    and t.paramId = 101
where
    p.paramId = 100
```